# How do I enable orientation change for a specific Storyboard scene?

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, screen-orientation

I have a systemic portrait-mode storyboard.

However I want to be able to rotate one scene to landscape mode without affecting other storyboard scenes.

Is this possible and how would I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Override the [`supportedInterfaceOrientations`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations) method in the view controller you want to allow landscape in, to return [`UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIInterfaceOrientationMask) or whichever value is suitable. This property is also configurable from the storyboard.

This will not affect the possible orientations of other view controllers; the app's UI orientation will automatically change back to portrait when you go to another scene.

You might need to uncheck Device Orientation options located in the project's General Settings for this to take effect (I didn't need to, but it seems to be necessary for some people):

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to uncheck the Device Orientation option within the App's General Settings for this to take effect.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee I use this in my app in numerous places, and I haven't unchecked that box. Maybe I changed something else to make it work, but I can't remember.

Comment: The Landscaping code didn't change anything till I remembered that the 'Portrait' was checked.   Unchecking that allowed the re-orientation to occur.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee you could also check *all* of the boxes, and enforce orientation with `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in your view controllers.

Comment: I just noticed that unchecking all Device Orientations defeats my original purpose: to SELECTIVELY govern the orientation.   So apparently I'm back to square one on this.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee try checking all the boxes, then setting supported orientations for all your view controllers in the storyboard (you should be able to ⌘+A and change it for all of them), then changing it selectively for the ones you need.